# Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check when creating RmiRegistryFactoryBean

Tags: rmi, spring-remoting

I get the following exception 8 times:

```
WARN  DefaultListableBeanFactor - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rmiRegistryFactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

When I create the following bean in my context:

```
    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean() {
        RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setPort(rmiConfig.getPort());
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setAlwaysCreate(true);

        return rmiRegistryFactoryBean;
    }
```

There is no explicit circular reference.